How can I remove tax class from coupon code?
I have activated coupon code NEXT50 in WooCommerce which is Rupees -50 and I want that tax class 'Tax @ 5%' on product and shipping should not be applied in coupon code and this tax should not be applied in invoice also. I am new to WooCommerce. Please let me know if there is any code or any other way. Thanks.
Tax Settings :
Enable tax rates and calculations - ticked
Prices entered with tax: Yes, I will enter prices inclusive of tax
Calculate tax based on: Customer billing address
Shipping
Tax class: Tax @ 5%
Display prices in the shop: Including tax
Display prices during cart and checkout: Including tax
Display tax totals: Itemized
These are the settings set by me and I cannot make any changes to any of these as per my requirement.
     // Adjust the coupon's taxable status
     add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount', 'set_coupon_taxable_false', 10, 5 );
     function set_coupon_taxable_false( $discount, $discounting_amount, $cart_item, $coupon, $cart ) {
     if ( $coupon === 'next50' ) {
     // Here you can manipulate the discount or the taxable status
     // Assuming you want to make it a non-taxable fee
     $fee = new WC_Cart_Fee();
     $fee-\>set_id( 'next50' );
     $fee-\>set_amount( -$discount );
     $fee-\>set_taxable( false ); // Set to false for this coupon
     $fee-\>set_total( -$discount );

    // Add the fee to the cart
    WC()->cart->add_fee( $fee->get_name(), $fee->get_amount(), $fee->is_taxable(), '' );

    // Optionally, return 0 if you want to avoid stacking discounts
    return 0;
    }

    return $discount;

    }

It didn't change anything.

Note that this question has already been asked multiple times and never been answered… I suppose that it's not really possible or maybe possible with an advanced coding, too long and complicate to fit in the scope of stack overflow.
